# How to implement multithreading with a return value?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been working on a calculator app in Java and I want to implement multithreading for this. I want to start a second thread, to calculate the answer for the given input. The only problem is, the calculation has to return a value and that value need to get displayed, but I don't know how to handle that. (I know its kind of useless to implement multithreading because the calculation doesn't even take a second, but I want to do it as practice and see if its possible)

Here you can see the code for which I want to start a second thread for:

```
public String calculate() {
//The input (StringBuilder) gets converted to an ArrayList
        String[] tmpArray = inputAsText.toString().split(" ");
        inputAsArrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(tmpArray));

//Other functions are called to perform calculations on
        inputAsArrayList = calculateFor("x", "÷");
        inputAsArrayList = calculateFor("+", "-");

//The answer gets retrieved from the arrarList and returned as a String
        String answer = String.valueOf(inputAsArrayList.get(0));
        clearInput();
        return answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deal with results from asynchronous code:

- Wait for the response to become available. This makes the results become available in the current thread.
- Use some kind of callback mechanism. The results are still not available in the current thread.

The waiting can be done using `Future` and one of its `get` methods. For callbacks, I prefer `CompletableFuture`, with methods like `thenAccept`. You can even easily hook it into something like the Swing/AWT Event Dispatcher:

```
future.thenAcceptAsync(action, EventQueue::invokeLater);
```

This works because the second argument needs to be an `Executor`, which is a functional interface with one method that takes a `Runnable` and returns nothing. That's exactly what `EventQueue.invokeLater` is.